# Including "boxes inside boxes" in baposter

Tags: boxes, block, baposter

I have divided my poster into `\headerbox` correctly.

I would like to modify the following example because in the results section I would like to make subdivisions or boxes in order to show different results. By the way, I have chosen this template but if you think it would be better to use a different one please say it. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.32]{baposter}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}



\usepackage{palatino}


\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\SET}[1]  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand{\MAT}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VEC}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Video}{\SET{V}}
\newcommand{\video}{\VEC{f}}
\newcommand{\track}{x}
\newcommand{\Track}{\SET T}
\newcommand{\LMs}{\SET L}
\newcommand{\lm}{l}
\newcommand{\PosE}{\SET P}
\newcommand{\posE}{\VEC p}
\newcommand{\negE}{\VEC n}
\newcommand{\NegE}{\SET N}
\newcommand{\Occluded}{\SET O}
\newcommand{\occluded}{o}

\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}


\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}


\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}


\begin{document}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}
\hyphenation{resolution occlusions}

\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=lightblue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=lightblue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=lightblue,
  textborder=roundedleft,
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.15\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {}
  %{\includegraphics[height=5em]{images/logoUPM.pdf}} 
  % Title
  {\bf\textsc{Tittle}\vspace{0.5em}}
  % Authors
  {Authors\\
   University\\
    mail@mail.com}


    \newcommand{\colouredcircle}{%
      \tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em); \draw[draw=black,fill=lightblue,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}

  \headerbox{Abstract}{name=problem,column=0,span=3, row=0}{
Text

    }
  \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,  below=problem}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0, above=bottom}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{Conclusions}{name=results,column=1,span=2, above=bottom}{
Text

 } 
 \headerbox{Results}{name=Shaped-Beam,below=problem, above=results,column=1,span=2,row=0}{
Text
  }

  \headerbox{Some Maths}{name=method,column=0,below=introduction,above=references}{

Text

  }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry that you haven't gotten any responses yet. Could you show the code of an example poster with `\headerbox`es set up? You could take a copy of your existing poster, and replace the text with some dummy text. This lowers the threshold for answering, as we don't have to set up a complete document ourselves, in other words, helping us help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use plain old `\section*` to make subheadings. If that is too plain, use for example `tcolorbox` and customize the box to your liking. For the code below, I just copied an example from the manual and changed the colors and text a bit.

Please add a comment if you have any more specific guidelines.

(I removed most of your preamble, because I don't really think it was relevant to the question.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.32]{baposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}
\hyphenation{resolution occlusions}

\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=lightblue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=lightblue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=lightblue,
  textborder=roundedleft,
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.15\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {}
  %{\includegraphics[height=5em]{images/logoUPM.pdf}} 
  % Title
  {\bf\textsc{Tittle}\vspace{0.5em}}
  % Authors
  {Authors\\
   University\\
    mail@mail.com}


  \headerbox{Abstract}{name=problem,column=0,span=3, row=0}{
Text

    }
  \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,  below=problem}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0, above=bottom}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{Conclusions}{name=results,column=1,span=2, above=bottom}{
Text

 } 
 \headerbox{Results}{name=Shaped-Beam,below=problem, above=results,column=1,span=2,row=0}{
\section*{First result}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title=Second result]
Awesome results.
\tcblower
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}  }

  \headerbox{Some Maths}{name=method,column=0,below=introduction,above=references}{

Text

  }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

## Columns

If you want content side by side there are several options. `tcolorbox`es can be placed side by side, so that is one option. `tcolorbox` also has the `raster` library for setting up matrix-like structure. The example in the code below is copied directly from the manual, and merely to show what the package can do. I don't really have much experience with the package, so if it looks interesting I advise you to search this site for examples, and looking at the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).

A more mundane setup would be to use the `multicols` environment from the `multicol` package. With this, the text will continue from the first to the second column. You can of course place images in here as well.

(This code, as the one above, is of course only intended to show a couple of examples.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.32]{baposter}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{demobox}[1][]{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,width=0.48\linewidth,nobeforeafter,box align=top,before=\noindent,#1}

\tcbuselibrary{raster,skins,fitting}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}
\hyphenation{resolution occlusions}

\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=lightblue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=lightblue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=lightblue,
  textborder=roundedleft,
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.15\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {}
  %{\includegraphics[height=5em]{images/logoUPM.pdf}} 
  % Title
  {\bf\textsc{Tittle}\vspace{0.5em}}
  % Authors
  {Authors\\
   University\\
    mail@mail.com}


  \headerbox{Abstract}{name=problem,column=0,span=3, row=0}{
Text

    }
  \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,  below=problem}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0, above=bottom}{
Text

  }

  \headerbox{Conclusions}{name=results,column=1,span=2, above=bottom}{
Text

 } 
 \headerbox{Results}{name=Shaped-Beam,below=problem, above=results,column=1,span=2,row=0}{
\begin{demobox}[title=First results]
\lipsum[1]
\end{demobox}\hfill
\begin{demobox}[title=Second results]
\lipsum[2]
\end{demobox}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster rows=3,raster height=0.4\linewidth,
enhanced,size=small,sharp corners,arc=8mm,colframe=red!50!black,
colback=yellow!10!white,watermark overzoom=1.0,fit algorithm=hybrid* ]
\begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners=northwest,boxrule=0pt,
watermark graphics=example-image]\end{tcolorbox}
\tcboxfit{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners=northeast,boxrule=0pt,
watermark graphics=example-image-a]\end{tcolorbox}
\tcboxfit{\lipsum[2]}
\begin{tcolorbox}[valign=center,center upper]Nine Boxes.\end{tcolorbox}
\tcboxfit{\lipsum[3]}
\begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners=southwest,boxrule=0pt,
watermark graphics=example-image-b]\end{tcolorbox}
\tcboxfit{\lipsum[4]}
\begin{tcolorbox}[rounded corners=southeast,boxrule=0pt,
watermark graphics=example-image-c]\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Stuff}
\lipsum[3-4]
\section*{Other stuff}
\lipsum[5]
\end{multicols}

}

  \headerbox{Some Maths}{name=method,column=0,below=introduction,above=references}{

Text

  }

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you bery much! 

What about doing horizontal subdivisions? Something like columns?

Comment: @Ignacio I added a couple of examples.

Comment: Hello again, 
In the same example, when the poster tittle is longer (two sentences) both are too close. How can I increase this separation?
Thank you very much

PD: For example removing the title line in the above example by :
 {\bf\textsc{Tittle Fake Tittle Fake Tittle Fake Tittle Fake Tittle Fake Tittle Fake Tittle Fake }\vspace{0.5em}}

Comment: @Ignacio This sounds like a completely different problem, so I would recommend that you create a new question about it.